# Trying to bind configuration: System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter can't be loaded

Tags: asp.net, configuration, asp.net-core, strong-typing, assembly-loading

I am trying to use ASP.NET Core configuration (specifically Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json) in a console application. When I call `IConfigurationRoot.Bind()` it throws a `FileNotFound` exception for the assembly `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`.

To my knowledge `TypeConverter` is in the `System.ComponentModel` namespaces in the *System* assembly, not the fictitious `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` assembly.

This appears to be a bug. Or am I missing something?

I'm targeting .NET 4.5.2, have referenced `System`, and have the following NuGet packages installed:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Is there a workaround or additional steps?

This also does not work:

```
ConfigurationBinder.Bind(config, myconfig);
```

It does not seem to matter whether my JSON represents string properties or a struct such as a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Seems like you created the wrong project type. You have to create the "Console Application (.NET Core)" and change it's target from `netcoreapp1.0` ot `net452` and remove the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package from dependencies. .NET Core applications use project.json to restore files, not packages.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been used to `TypeConverter` being in `System`. I poked around NuGet and found there is indeed an assembly, `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` as part of .NET Core. Installing that package fixed my problem.