# After installing System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, NuGet breaks

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-core, .net-4.5.2

I have a console application project targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2. I had to install [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/) to get past a [strongly typed configuration binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38773481/64348).

After doing this, NuGet `install-package` and `update-package` throw the exception:

> An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.4.1.0' from source '....'.           0

How can I get around this without having to uninstall `TypeConverter`?

Comment: Is it the general C# console app? Do you use the latest NuGet version? I couldn't repro it in my side using VS2015, if you remove the package from your solution folder, and then re-install this package again, how about the result?

Comment: I guess is with a portable or core app, might want to add that as a tag on in the info.

Comment: Not so familiar with core projects, is the `.net-4.5.2` tag actually valid?

Comment: It is in this case. I am actually building a Windows service that targets .NET 4.5.2, but want to use the JSON strongly typed configuration that's part of ASP.NET Core (because I don't want to re-invent the wheel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had version 3.3 of NuGet, what came with Update 1 of VS 2015. Installing NuGet 3.4.4 fixed the issue.